# Customize Devise pathnames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, devise, routes

I am trying to customize the urls created by the devise gem:

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {
    sign_in: 'login',
    sign_out: 'logout',
    sign_up: 'signup',
    password: 'forgot',
    confirmation: 'activate',
    invitation: 'invite'
}
```

This works well. It creates the following routes:

```
/login -> sessions#new
/logout -> sessions#destroy
/signup -> registrations#new
/forgot/new -> passwords#new
/forgot/edit -> passwords#edit
/activate/new -> confirmations#new
/activate/show -> confirmations#show
/invite/new -> invitations#new
/invite/accept -> invitations#edit
/invite/remove -> invitations#destroy
```

But instead I want to achieve something like this:

```
/login -> sessions#new
/logout -> sessions#destroy
/signup -> registrations#new
/forgot -> passwords#new
/recover -> passwords#edit
/activate -> confirmations#new
/confirm -> confirmations#show
/invite -> invitations#new
/invite/accept -> invitations#edit
/invite/remove -> invitations#destroy
```

How can change the path names of the unique controller methods with devise (without manually rewriting them all together with a custom controller)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes), it looks like you can use a block to more define the routes as you would normally.

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, ...]
as :user do
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  ...
end
```