# Devise: Duplicate routing entries despite my custom entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

When I run `rake routes | grep sessions` I'm getting duplicate entries despite already having my own settings.

Here's my output: (these aren't all of the duplicates btw.)

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy
               login GET    /login(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
                     POST   /login(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
              logout DELETE /logout(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
```

The top three are the default routing settings from Devise and the bottom three are the ones I've added in `config/routes.rb`.

Here is sample of my `config/routes.rb` file pertaining to Devise:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#index'

  # Users
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
     # I override a few actions in my own controller so I needed this
     registrations: 'users/registrations',
  }

  # FYI: as is an alias for devise_scope
  as :user do
    # devise/sessions_controller handlers
    get    'login',           to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    post   'login',           to: 'devise/sessions#create'
    delete 'logout',          to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'

    #.... other registrations controller settings that are also getting duplicated
  end

  # .... all my other application routes
end
```

I guess what I'm asking is, how to I suppress the default routes from Devise since I've created my own? If you need more of my `rake routes` output or `config/routes.rb` file I can submit the whole thing.

**EDIT:**

Ok looks like I need to add a `:path_names` hash to my `devise_for :users` block. From https://devhints.io/devise, I can see a selection of options for the paths at the end of the page. Also removing the `:path` option altogether gives me an unaliased version which matches what I wanted.

Here's what I had to do to get it (mostly) right:

```
devise_for :users, :path => '',
  :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'sign-in',
    :sign_out => 'sign-out',
    :password => '',
    :confirmation => 'verification',
    :unlock => 'unblock',
    :registration => 'register',
    :sign_up => '' },
    # ignore this, changing this probably wont fix anything plus I need it.
    controllers: {
     registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

Its not totally perfect so Ill give the answer to anyone who can show me how to get:

```
                    root GET    /                          pages#index
        new_user_session GET    /sign-in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /sign-in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /sign-out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
cancel_user_registration GET    /register/cancel(.:format) users/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /register(.:format)        users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /register/edit(.:format)   users/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /register(.:format)        users/registrations#update
                          PUT    /register(.:format)       users/registrations#update
                          DELETE /register(.:format)       users/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /register(.:format)       users/registrations#create
                 password GET    /password(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
           reset_password GET    /reset-password(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH  /reset-password(.:format) devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /reset-password(.:format) devise/passwords#update
                          POST   /password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create

 I DONT WANT THE FOLLOWING IN MY ROUTES:
       new_user_password GET    /new(.:format)             devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /edit(.:format)            devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /                          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /                          devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /                          devise/passwords#create
```

I could change `:password => ''` to `:password => 'reset-password'` but then I get these:

```
 new_user_password GET  /reset-password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password GET  /reset-password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                   POST /reset-password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
```

When what I want is this:

```
 new_user_password GET  /password(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
edit_user_password GET  /reset-password(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                   POST /password(.:format)       devise/passwords#create
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like I need to add a `:path_names` hash to my `devise_for :users` block. From https://devhints.io/devise, I can see a selection of options for the paths at the end of the page. Also removing the `:path` option altogether gives me an unaliased version which matches what I wanted.

**EDIT:**

On top of what I found (and included in my question) I also found the `:skip` option. Someone has already asked a similar question that I have and the perfect answer to this (telling Devise not to generate ANY of the routes I want to override) is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46900434/43792